# Unable to install Django: DNS server not authoritative for zone

Tags: dns

I've been trying to install Django for some time, but whatever I do, I always get the same error.

```
DNS server not authoritative for zone.
```

It's the same when I use pip, it's the same when I download Django and try to install it with the suggested command from Django website:
    python setup.py install

I've tried to do it with both Python 3.3 and 3.4 AND with Django 1.7.7 and Django 1.8 (1.7.7 was the latest when i started trying and 1.8 is the latest now...).

I found sth about specifying DNS servers as authoritative for zone, but it seems to be for servers only: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780197(v=ws.10).aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
If you get this error, go ahead and write the command like it's supposed to be:

```
python -m pip install Django==x.x.x
```

FYI I didn't do that.